# How do I change the value of the SlideMaster.Height in PowerPoint 2016 VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to automate the process of changing the height in the Slide Size dialog in the Slide Master system with VBA. When I try to change it, VBA informs me that I'm not permitted to assign a value to ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height because it is read-only.

I've studied the ActivePresentation object tree and have figured out to acquire the height value (with ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height), but the following line results in a Compile Error:

```
ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height = 1189
```

Changing the SlideHeight with...

```
ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight = 1189
```

does change the height of the slide, but it doesn't have the same effect as changing the height through the Slide Master system. The primary question at this stage is if it's possible to change ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height with VBA, or is the Read-Only status immutable?

```
Sub test()

    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height = 1189 'Compile Error...can't assign to read-only property

    ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight = 1189 'Changes the height of the slides, _
    but doesn't change the size of text within Shape elements like I need it to do.

End Sub
```

Here's some background...

Through a bit of trial and error, I've determined that if I change the dimensions of the slides using the slide master, the default text for Shapes is set how I want it (at pitch 18). If I don't change the dimensions in the Slide Master, the text for Shapes remains at 31. Even if a new shape is created, the font is changed to 18 and that shape is set as the default shape, if text is pasted onto the slide (with CTRL-v or Paste Special-Unformatted Text), the shape that gets created has a text-size of 31.

Just to be clear, if the default is set to 18 and I create another new Shape via Insert>Shapes, then that new shape is automatically set to 18. It's only when I paste text (using either CTRL-v or Paste Special - Unformatted) directly on the slide does it become 31.

The only thing that does what I want is making a slight change to the Slide Master Slide Size. Changing the height from 1188 to 1189 forces all of the shapes on all of the slides to go from 31 to 18. Any new text that gets pasted in the slide comes in as a shape containing 18 text.

The reason I'm posting this on Stack Overflow and not on Super User is because I have to automate this change...we have thousands of presentations to modify.

Comment: It's not clear HOW you're changing the Slide Master height. It might help if you explained this part.

Comment: By clicking the Slide Size button in the Slide Master menu and then changing the value in the dialog that comes up. Changes here are reflected in ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height...For example, if I change the height in the Slide Size dialog to from 14.5 to 14.51, that property is also changed in VBA (from 1188 to 1189).

Comment: OK, I see. Doing this is the same as changing the slide size from the normal view. Either way it invokes a dialog where you choose Maximize or Ensure Fit, and that in turn triggers some internal code that adjusts shapes/text sizes and so on to the new size. Same thing happens when you change the slide size from Normal view, and either one has the same effect. But when you change the slide size via VBA, it doesn't hook into that dialog. If you want the same effect, you'd have to write code to make it happen. Lots and Lots of code.  BTDT.

Comment: OK good to know. Something else I learned today is that I can get text to paste in at 18 if I change the Slide Master theme. I played around a bit with SlideMaster.ApplyTheme, but kept getting a run-time error (429...ActiveX component can't create object), suggesting that I don't have the correct DLL somewhere. Before I go down that rabbit hole, could you tell me if ApplyTheme can be used in this way? I should also note that I'm opening PowerPoint with Excel using FileSystemObject.

Comment: Something else...we've been running PowerPoint here since before pptx. Recently, we did a mass-conversion of all of our old ppt files to pptx. Interestingly, all of these converted files do not automatically adjust the text within shapes from 31 to 18. However, when text is pasted in with CTRL-v in these converted files (after the theme is changed), the size is 18. Files that were created as pptx from the beginning automatically adjust the text size in the current shapes and set the default text to 18 (when using CTRL-v) when the SlideMaster theme is changed.

Comment: The ApplyTheme method works from within PowerPoint (not when manipulating a PowerPoint Presentation object from Excel). Creating a copy of the Office Theme and then applying it to the Slide Master changes the presentation so that text pasted in from the clipboard is set at 18 and not 31.

Comment: We'd have to see the code you're using around ApplyTheme to guess at why you're getting errors with it. It should work against Presentation, Master, Slide or SlideRange objects.  BTW, for the problem presentations, have you set the default text format?  That generally (though not always) controls size and formatting of new text.